# Error setting up STS for Grails

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm trying to install STS 2.9.1 *Grails support* and *Groovy Eclipse* extension but I'm getting a notification:

**The following connectors are not available: Grails Support**

**Proceed with the isntallation anyways?**

What's up with this?

I dont know if its relevant but I have java 1.7u4 and I've manualy installed Grails 1.3.7. I have Windows 7 64bit and installing STS 64bit.

I've tried tried installing just Groovy Eclipse extension ignoring the message but installation broke. So I've cleaned all files, reinstalled the STS, installed again just Groovy Eclipse extension. And then tried to install Grails support. The process started but it broke and this is the error I've got:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=com.springsource.sts.ide,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/37/milestone/plugins/org.aspectj.ajde_1.7.0.20120309122400.jar.
>   Read timed out Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/37/milestone/plugins/org.eclipse.ajdt.core.source_2.2.0.e37x-20120314-1100.jar.
>   Read timed out

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the proxy settings? Window - Preferences - General - Network Connections. I have had similar problems in the past...

Comment: @marko Do you have any suggestions about what should I do with the proxies?

Comment: Well, first you could try to play with the "Active provider". Try the different settings and see if it does anything.

Comment: i know this  is old, but this happened to me...
Solved: manually installed via "Install new software" menu from http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/update/e3.6